# Why are 'must' and 'must not' both negative and how can I separate them?

Tags: grammar

While studying Japanese I came across some grammar that really confuses me:

```
ここから、始まってはいけない
```

Ok, it says 'you must not start from here', which seems agreeable because the sentence is in a negative form. However then this sentence appears:

```
ここから、始まらなくてはいけない
```

Which roughly translates to 'you must start from here'. Why is this sentence also negative? Why are 'must' and 'must not' both written in a negative form and how can I tell them apart?

Comment: please check that you transcribed the second example correctly

Comment: Should be right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 始まってはいけない

Its components and their "polarity":

- 始まる: positive (to begin)
- いけない: negative

Construction: 始まって（て form of 始まる） + は + いけない

And, positive * negative = **negative**

So, this roughly means "must not start" (negative)

### 始まらなくてはいけない

This is "positive" because it contains a "double negative"

Its components and "polarity"

- 始まらない: negative (to not begin)
- いけない: negative

Construction: 始まらなくて（て form of 始まらない） + は + いけない

And, negative * negative = **positive**

This roughly means "must not not start", or "must start", because the "not"s cancel each other

Comment: Multiple negation is**n't** actually **un**acceptable in English, so I'd probably reword that section slightly.  Multiple marking of a single semantic negation is (for the most part) non-standard in English, but that's not really related to the Japanese example, in which each semantic negation is expressed only once.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for reining that one in. Removed reference to language dependence as suggested.